# PostgreSQL ON BEFORE DELETE trigger not firing on a parent table in an inheritance scenario

Tags: postgresql, triggers, database-partitioning

I have a parent table and multiple inherited child tables that I'm using as partitions. I'm not using the new method in PG 10 because I manually calculate the routing and require processing on each `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` operation.

I have this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_collections_all
  BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT OR DELETE
  ON cms.collections
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE cms.collections_process();
```

It fires and works correctly on `INSERT` and `UPDATE`, but not on `DELETE`.

I added the following line as line #1 in `cms.collections_process()` to prove `DELETE` isn't firing:

```
  raise exception '(%)', TG_OP;
```

The row deleted.

The [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html) state:

> In contrast, row-level triggers are fired for all affected partitions
>   or child tables.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UPDATE`s and `DELETE`s on the parent table will affect rows in the child tables (if you don't specify `ONLY`), but triggers will only be fired by data modifications directed directly against the table with the trigger on it:

```
CREATE TABLE parent(id integer, val text);
CREATE TABLE child() INHERITS (parent);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION inh_trigger() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE 'Called by %', TG_OP;
   RETURN CASE WHEN TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN OLD ELSE NEW END;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER inh_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON parent
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE inh_trigger();
```

Only `INSERT`s directly on `parent` file the trigger:

```
test=> INSERT INTO parent VALUES (1, 'one');
NOTICE:  Called by INSERT
INSERT 0 1
test=> INSERT INTO child VALUES (2, 'two');
INSERT 0 1
```

The same holds for `UPDATE` and `DELETE`:

```
test=> UPDATE parent SET val = 'changed' WHERE id = 1;
NOTICE:  Called by UPDATE
UPDATE 1
test=> UPDATE parent SET val = 'changed' WHERE id = 2;
UPDATE 1
test=> DELETE FROM parent WHERE id = 1;
NOTICE:  Called by DELETE
DELETE 1
test=> DELETE FROM parent WHERE id = 2;
DELETE 1
```

This seems to be in direct contrast to the sentence in the documentation you quote, or at least the sentence is highly misleading.

I'd say that this is a documentation bug, and you should complain about it.

Comment: The thing is, I'm running all ops against the patent, but only delete is not firing. Yet it is somehow deleting in the child. The trigger is the only code that routes.

Comment: As you see in my example, the trigger also doesn't fire if you update `parent`, but the row is in `child`. It looks like you'll have to define the trigger on all inheritance children.

Comment: Thank you, I see that. PG must scan all child tables to find the record as it has no other way of finding it. I think I need to approach this a different way: have dedicated UPDATE and DELETE functions and disallow access to these ops (except via the function).